# show tooltip just on row's header of Telerik DataGridVieww

Tags: wpf, telerik, tooltip, radgridview

I use these codes to show data preview as ToolTip:

```
private void dataGrid1_RowLoaded(object sender, RowLoadedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = e.Row as GridViewRow;
        if (row != null)
        {
            var textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.Text = "...";
            textBlock.DataContext = row;

            var toolTip = new ToolTip()
            {
                Content = textBlock,
            };

            toolTip.Opened += dataGrid1_ToolTipOpening;
            ToolTipService.SetToolTip(row, toolTip);
        }

    }

    private void dataGrid1_ToolTipOpening(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         GridViewRow row = null;

            var tooltip = e.OriginalSource as ToolTip;
            if (tooltip.Content is UCPreview)
            {
                return;
            }
            else if (tooltip.Content is TextBlock)
            {
                var content = tooltip.Content as TextBlock;
                row = content.DataContext as GridViewRow;
            }
            var gridViewRow = row.Item as DataRowView;
            if (gridViewRow != null)
            {
               //initial UCPreview                    
            }           
    }
}
```

now, I want to the ToolTip to be showed only when mouse is on row's Header. unfortunately GridViewRow doesn't have Header Property. how can i solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I have not misinterpreted your question , try this you can do that by setting tooltip in DataGridColumnHeader Style like

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Key="dghStyle">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource dghStyle}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I hope this will help . This is just workaround you can set ToolTop according to your requirement.

Comment: my columns generate automatically and i want to tooltip activate on header of rows.

Comment: then use RartgetType DataGridRowHeader instead of DataGridColumnHeader in the above xaml.

Comment: I use Telerik Grid, (telerik:RadGridView)